# DataSheet View - Uneditable Field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Pivot/CrossTab Form that i need to have it so that the left Field/Column is uneditable while the other column/fields are editable.

Is there a way to change the color of the TextBox to be non-Grey when Disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't disable, Lock, then you can have any colour you want.